# Let $a_n$ be a sequence s.t $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_nb_n=0$ $\forall b_n$ real sequence. Show $\exists n_0\in N$ s.t $n\geq n_0 \implies a_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n b_n = 0$ for all real sequence $(b_n)$. Show that there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n = 0$ for all $n\geq n_0 $.

I thought of doing maybe by contradiction. Suppose that $a_n\neq 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then let us construct $(b_n)$ as $\frac{1}{a_n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By hypothesis, $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n b_n = 0$ for all real sequence $(b_n)$. But there lies a contradiction. Using our constructed $b_n$,  $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n b_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n \cdot \frac{1}{a_n} = 1$. Does it suffice to prove what the question asks?

Thank you!

Comment: This is pretty much the idea, but the converse of "there exists $n_0$ such that $\forall n \geqslant n_0, a_n=0$" is "for all $n_0$, there exists $n \geqslant n_0$ such that $a_n \neq 0$". So you can define $b_n=1/a_n$ only for some $n$. So $a_n b_n$ can be zero or $1$ depending on $a_n=0$ or $a_n \neq 0$

Comment: How can I correct this? Maybe defining $(b_n)$ being $\frac{1}{a_n}$ such that for all $n_0$, there does exists $n \geq n0$ such that $a_n \neq 0$? And from this wherre can I find the contradiction?

Comment: Assume there is no $n_0$ such that $\forall n \geqslant n_0, a_n=0$, then define $b_n=0$ when $a_n=0$ and $b_n=1/a_n$ otherwise. The sequence $a_nb_n$ will always be $0$ or $1$ and show that indeed it doesn't tend to $0$ because it is $1$ for infinitly many $n$

Comment: @AlexL Very clever !